# Current Eclipse plugin for duplicated code

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, code-duplication, sonarlint

Is there a plugin or feature dedicated to find duplicated code from within eclipse?

The SDD plugin seems to be outdated and dead.
SonarLint does not show duplicated code.

i want to see duplicated code and not other noise as pmd would introduce (i think)

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [CPD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html)

> Duplicate code can be hard to find, especially in a large project. But PMD’s Copy/Paste Detector (CPD) can find it for you

For example:

> Minimum required options: Just give it the minimum duplicate size and the source directory:
>
> ```
> $ ./run.sh cpd --minimum-tokens 100 --files /usr/local/java/src/java
> ```

Comment: i need a tool integrated into Eclipse. Finding duplicate code is not the problem - we are using SoanQube

Answer (score 1):

The most popular Eclipse plug-in for that is [***eclipse-pmd***](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-pmd) which integrates [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) with its [Copy/Paste Detector (CPD)](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.9.0/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html).

There are also [other plug-ins](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/pmd) that integrate [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/), and probably also some commercial plug-ins to find duplicated code.

Comment: i tired this plugin. it does not work out of the box. after installation the is no pmd menu nor an pmd perspective (as seen on a youtube video). all other plugins are also outdated

Comment: Outdated? [eclipse-pmd 1.14] has been released three months ago](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/releases). See [here how to activate PMD for a project](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html). Which other plug-ins did you try?